# Change button text based on hidden div

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have two simple divs with a button to toggle their visibility. I'd like to have the title of the button show the title of the hidden div. So when you have the "Landscape" div visible, the button will say "Switch to Portrait". When showing "Portrait" div, the button should say "Switch to Landscape".

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
    <div class="panel panel-heading">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default switch">16:9/9:16</button>
    </div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <div class="span4 cropme" id="landscape" style="width: 1136px; height: 720px;"></div>
    <div class="span4 cropme" id="portrait" style="width: 720px; height: 1136px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
$('#portrait').hide();
$('.switch').click(function (){
  $('#portrait').toggle();
  $('#landscape').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ursLfw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpp8w925/)

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default switch">Switch to Portrait</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#portrait').hide();
$('.switch').click(function (){
    $(this).text("Switch to "+($('#portrait').is(":visible") ? "Portrait" : "Landscape"));
  $('#portrait').toggle();
  $('#landscape').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I like this version a little more. No need to use a title text within the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#portrait').hide();
$('.switch').click(function () {
    $('#portrait, #landscape').toggle();
    $('button').text('Switch to ' + $('.cropme:hidden').text())
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z2ursLfw/4/)**

Comment: This is what I was looking for, except I needed to show the text of the hidden div, so `.cropme:hidden`

Comment: I think I updated my answer while you were entering your comment. Check the latest fiddle/update in my answer.